# How to include in a query multiple fields with the avgs of each of their balances

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to make a query that includes the consultant last name, which is in the Table 1, plus the average balance for each of the consultant's clients, which are in table 2. The consultants are matched in each table with the ConsltNum. What sql code can accomplish that? Thanks in advance

Table 1

```
ConsltNum   LastName    FirstName   Street  City    State   ZipCode Hours   Rate
19  Turner  Christopher 554 Brown Dr.   Tri City    FL  32889   40  $22.50
22  Jordan  Patrick 2287 Port Rd.   Easton  FL  33998   40  $22.50
35  Allen   Sarah   82 Elliott St.  Lizton  FL  34344   35  $20.00
51  Shields Tom 373 Lincoln Ln. Sunland FL  39876   10  $15.00
```

Table 2

```
ClientNum   ClientName  Street  City    State   ZipCode Balance CreditLimit ConsltNum
143 Hershey, Jarrod 135 E. Mill Street  Easton  FL  33998   $1,904.55   $2,500.00   19
175 Goduto, Sean    12 Saratoga Parkway Tri City    FL  32889   $2,814.55   $5,000.00   19
299 Two Crafty Cousins  9787 NCR 350 West   Sunland FL  39876   $8,354.00   $10,000.00  22
322 Prichard's Pizza & Pasta    501 Air Parkway Lizton  FL  34344   $7,335.55   $10,000.00  35
363 Salazar, Jason  56473 Cherry Tree Dr.   Easton  FL  33998   $900.75 $2,500.00   35
405 Fisherman's Spot Shop   49 Elwood Ave.  Harpersburg FL  31234   $4,113.40   $7,500.00   19
449 Seymour, Lindsey    4091 Brentwood Ln   Amo FL  34466   $557.70 $5,000.00   22
458 Bonnie's Beautiful Boutique 9565 Ridge Rd.  Tri City    FL  32889   $4,053.80   $7,500.00   22
677 Yates, Nick 231 Day Rd. Sunland FL  39876   $2,523.80   $2,500.00   35
733 Howler, Laura   1368 E. 1000 S. Lizton  FL  34344   $3,658.05   $5,000.00   22
826 Harpersburg Bank    65 Forrest Blvd.    Harpersburg FL  31234   $6,824.55   $10,000.00  19
867 MarketPoint Sales   826 Host St.    Easton  FL  33998   $3,089.00   $5,000.00   19

SELECT LastName, AVG(balance) OVER(ConsltNum)
```

Comment: If you have already made an attempt, consider posting the query/queries you have tried. This may aid others in providing a more substantial explanation, clarification, etc. along with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can join and aggregate:

```
select 
    t1.[LastName],
    avg(t2.[Balance] as [Avg_Client_Balance]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.[ConsltNum] = t2.[ConsltNum]
group by t1.[ConsltNum], t1.[LastName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can aggregate and join

```
select c.ConsltNum, c.LastName, a.avg_balance, a.total_balance
from (
    select ConsltNum, avg(Balance) avg_balance, sum(Balance) total_balance 
    from table2 group by ConsltNum 
) a
join table1 c on a.ConsltNum = c.ConsltNum
```